# python pandas HDFStore: how to append dataframe containing complex numbers

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

I wish to store a pandas DataFrame with a column that has dtype=complex128 to an hdf5 database using hdfstore. However I get an error. Here is some example code:

```
import pandas as pd                            
import numpy as np

store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')

df = pd.DataFrame({'qty1': np.fft.fft(np.exp(range(10))),
                   'qty2': np.random.randn(10)})

print df

store.append('df', df)
```

The error message is:

> > TypeError: to avoid confusions with PyTables 1.X complex atom names, please use `ComplexAtom(itemsize=N)`, where N=8 for single precision complex atoms, and N=16 for double precision complex atoms
> >     Closing remaining open files:test.h5...done

How does one store pandas DataFrames with one or more complex number columns?

FYI - my pandas version is 0.13.1, numpy version is 1.8.1, PyTables is 3.1.1.

Comment: this is not implemented atm; pls file a github issue with an enhancement request; pull-requests are welcome!

Comment: @Jeff - Thanks! I will file a github issue.